# Automatically Click related multi check boxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a check box of 1st screen,related all check boxes on 2nd screen should automatically clicked.Can you tell me how can I achieve this ?

**Note :** Actually I am having 2 different screens.When I click 1st screen's check box, say "grooming" then automatically all the related check boxes of 2nd screen should be clicked(ie. all Grooming check boxes )

**Screen 1 :**

**Source Code for S 1:**

```
<div class="padded-content">

    <h2>Extra Services</h2>
    <ul id="extra-services-details">
        <% foreach (var extra in Model.Provider.Services)
           {  %><li>
               <input id="<%: extra.Id %>"
                   type="checkbox" name="extraService" value="<%: extra.Id %>" /><label for="<%: extra.Id  %>"><%: extra.Name%></label></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

**Screen 2 :**

**Source code for S 2 :**

```
<div class="extra-service">
        <table id="extras">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <% 
                        foreach (var d in Model.Dates)
                        { 
                    %><th colspan="<%: Model.Pets.Count() %>"><%: Html.DisplayFor(m => d.Date, "DateIcon") %>
                    </th>
                    <% 
                        } 
                    %>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: left;">Service</th>
                    <% 
                        foreach (var d in Model.Dates)
                        {
                            if (Model.Pets.Count() > 1)
                            {
                                foreach (var pet in Model.Pets)
                                { 
                    %><th id="<%: pet.Key%>"><%: pet.Name%></th>
                    <% 
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                    %><th></th>
                    <%
                            }
                        } 
                    %>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% 
                    var extras = Model.Provider.OfferredServices.Where(s => s.IsAnExtra && s.Key != Model.Service.Key).OrderBy(s => s.DisplayIndex).ToList();

                    foreach (var service in extras)
                    {  %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%: service.Name %> </td>
                    <% 
                        foreach (var d in Model.Dates)
                        {
                            foreach (var pet in Model.Pets)
                            { %><td style="text-align: center">
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                    value="<%: pet.Key %>-<%: d.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") %>-<%: service.Key %>" />
                            </td>
                    <% 
                            }
                        } 
                    %>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: please share html code instead of images

Comment: @ArunPJohny OK I will update.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#extra-services-details input:checkbox').change(function(){
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('table tbody tr').eq(idx).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)
})
```

Comment: @Sampath yes it should work.... if you can share the generated html of both the `ul` and `table` it can be tested

Comment: "$('table tbody tr').eq(idx).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)" statement selects no items.Can you tell me why ?

Comment: On my case index is not suitable. So can you suggest another method.B'cos there can be more than 1 index when having multiple check boxes.As shown on my images.Need to select all "grooming" check boxes when I select screen 1 check box.Any idea ?

Comment: @Sampath instead of the server side html template can you post the generated html...

Comment: +1 for your support.I have completed above task bit different way than your solution.But you have showed me the path.I will update my solution later.Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

In the checkbox click event:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]')
       .prop({ checked: $(this).is(':checked') });
```

This will find all checkboxes in the same row and check them. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Actually I am having 2 different screens.When I click 1st screen's check box, say "grooming" then automatically all the related check boxes of 2nd screen should be clicked(ie. all Grooming check boxes ).